# How to get plugin's folders permission

Tags: plugins

I have built a wordpress plugin (wp-content/plugins/MyPlugin) and I would to check some folders permission inside the MyPlugin directory.

My problem is that I don't what Wordpress constant or what PHP function I should use to target on of these directories.

```
if( !is_writable(WP_PLUGIN_URL.'MyFolder') )
{
    echo 'NOK'.'<hr>';  
}
```

This piece of code always returns 'NOK' whereas I am 100% sure 'MyFolder' is actually writable .

Can you give me some piece of advice here to get the right file in order to target any folder that would be in my plugin directory?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`? `WP_PLUGIN_URL` is responsible for URLs.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to make it work with: plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'MyFolder';